# read file with single line into R in fread or read.table

Tags: r, data.table, fread, read.table

I want to read a txt file into R

this file has only file line, like this

```
1 NYC 2013-12-30 82 PM2.5 Ⅱ fair 2 London 2013-12-30 66 PM10.0 Ⅱ good
```

there're no \n in this file, and all the what I want is a data.table incorporating these information

like this:

```
 1 NYC    2013-12-30 82 PM2.5  Ⅱ fair
 2 London 2013-12-30 66 PM10.0 Ⅱ good
```

Luckily, there're no NAs in the file, also I know for sure there're 7 fields for each observations. Could I achieve this using fread?

or read.table?

I tried this

```
test <- read.table("1.txt) # the file name..
test <- matrix(test, ncol = 7)
```

and `scan`,`as.array`. all failed.

Could you give some suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux and `data.table` 1.8.11 I'd do:

```
fread("sed -r 's/(([^ ]+ +){7})/\\1\\n/g' yourfile | sed 's/ $//'")
```

Comment: Ouch!  Using `sed` is "awk"ward :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft better `awk` or otherwise solutions are very welcome - this seems pretty straightforward to me, but then I use `sed` and `regex` a lot

Comment: apologies.  I meant the entire comment purely as a unix joke.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft understood, but better solutions are still very welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing might just be to use `scan` directly. You could probably also use `read.fwf`, but I think that's more complex.

```
> data.frame(matrix(scan('2.txt', what='character'), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))
Read 14 items
  X1     X2         X3 X4     X5  X6   X7
1  1    NYC 2013-12-30 82  PM2.5  || fair
2  2 London 2013-12-30 66 PM10.0  || good
```

Comment: Agreed: only use `read.fwf` if you have whitespace in the middle of some desired fields (and thus can't use the default separators).  If the OP has, say  "Buenos Aires" in there, he'll have to work harder.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a second way with `scan`:

```
t(do.call(rbind, scan(text=t, what=replicate(7, character()))))
#      [,1] [,2]     [,3]         [,4] [,5]     [,6] [,7]  
# [1,] "1"  "NYC"    "2013-12-30" "82" "PM2.5"  "?"  "fair"
# [2,] "2"  "London" "2013-12-30" "66" "PM10.0" "?"  "good"
```