# R data.table fwrite to fread space delimiter and empties

Tags: r, data.table

I am having problems using fread with " " as delimiter and interspersed blank values.  For example, this:

```
dt <- data.table(1:5,1:5,1:5) #make a simple table
dt[3,"V2" := NA] #add a blank in the middle to illustrate the problem
fwrite(dt, file = "dt.csv", sep = " ") #save to file
dt <- fread("dt.csv", sep = " ") #try to retrieve
```

The fread fails with: "Stopped early on line 4. Expected 3 fields but found 2."  The problem seems to be that with the NA value in the middle column, fwrite gives value|space|space|value, then fread doesn't recognize the implied blank value in the middle.

I understand it would be simple to use another delimiter in the first place.  However, is it possible to get fread to reproduce the original dt here?

**EDIT WITH A READ-SIDE SOLUTION**:

I found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215177/how-to-read-when-delimiter-is-space-and-missing-values-are-blank).  It's a bit confusing because it gives a solution, but then the solution later stopped working.  On pursuing some other leads the closest I've now found to a read-side solution with fread() is with a Unix command like this:

```
dt <- fread(cmd="wsl sed -r 's/ /,/g' dt.csv") #converts spaces to commas on the way in
```

On Windows 10 I had to do some trial and error to get my system to run Unix commands.  The "wsl" part seems to depend on the system.  [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srzYBXO1Bqo) video was helpful, and I used the first method he describes there. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990571/read-file-with-single-line-into-r-in-fread-or-read-table?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349273/how-to-read-unquoted-extra-r-with-data-tablefread) question provides a bit more on sed with fread.  The latter says sed comes with rTools, although I did not try that.

Comment: It might be more effective to show the raw contents of your sample text file (in a code block) instead of trying to create it programmatically. While I applaud the effort, ultimately, writing it not important here and going to long efforts to do so can be distracting. (It also allows you to more aptly mimic the actual text file you're trying to import.)

Comment: @r2evans thanks, I'll think about that.  I did think it was interesting that, what fwrite puts out, fread misinterprets in this simple case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe export `NA` as something other than `""` by default

Here I use `@`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(1:5,1:5,1:5) #make a simple table
dt[3,"V2" := NA] #add a blank in the middle to illustrate the problem
fwrite(dt, file = "dt.csv", sep = " ", na="@") #save to file
dt <- fread("dt.csv", sep = " ",na.strings = "@") #try to retrieve
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense as another option on the write side.  I'm still curious if one can't treat consecutive delimiters as implying a blank value in between on the read side.

Comment: if you put `" "` as `na` and `na.string` parameters it will interfere with `strip.white` parameter and fails to catch it anyway.